# Can all math expressions be converted into trees?

Tags: meta-math

Operators usually have different notations (prefix, infix, postfix, ... ?), but expressions using them can all be transformed into expression trees.

E.g. `((a + b) * c) + 7`

[image]

Is this true for all expressions used in mathematics?

What insights can this give us?

Comment: @Unit No it's not - higher-arity operations just yield trees which split more than twice. (And even that can be gotten around via Currying.)